# Using Ajax and passing JS variable to php variable, $_POST not recognizing data value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using AJAX to pass a javascript variable to PHP. Everything was working well and dandy, and then I changed the security of how my php functions will execute. Here is my javscript code:

```
function writetofile(file, wellname, api){
   $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'process.php',
    data: { 
        api: api,
        wellname: wellname,
        fileName: file,
        writetoFile: true
    },
    success: function(data){
        output(api + " : " + wellname + " has been added to: " + file);
    }
});
```

}

PHP:

```
// process.php
if ($_POST['writetoFile'])){ // i need to check here if writetofile is true, which it is
    $api = $_POST['api'];
    $wellname = $_POST['wellname'];
    $fileName = $_POST['fileName'];
    $break = "\n";
    $str = $api. " : ". $wellname . $break;
    $file = fopen($fileName,"a");
    fwrite($file, $str);
    fclose($file);
}
```

when I execute the javascript code, it doesn't write to the file, and yes, I have checked to see if the ajax request was accepted. It is, but i tried doing:

PHP

```
if ($_POST['writetoFile'] === true)){}
```

but that doesn't seem to be working either. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What happens when you `var_dump($_POST)`? You're also not doing any error checking. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: let me add that and see what comes up

Comment: Wow i feel really stupid, I am so sorry for asking this. I have been staring at this damn piece of code for the last hour only to find that I had an extra ) in my code... Please don't downvote this. Thank you. The error set up did hel me a lot though.

Comment: Is this your entire code or is it just a part of it? If this is really the code you are using, what bothers me is this: `if ($_POST['writetoFile'])){` -> check the number of `)`. You have two.

Comment: Glad you found the problem @macas.

Answer (score 1):

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

You'll find that you have an extra closing parentheses in your `if` statement -

```
if ($_POST['writetoFile'] === true))
                             ------^
```